# how to detect change in useState except for first rendering?

Tags: react-native, hook, use-effect, use-state

If I change text of TextInput then I change useState named `name` and `setName`.

```
const [name, setName] = useState("")

  <TextInput
    defaultValue={meData?.me?.name}
    onChangeText={(text) => setNameValue(text)}
  />
```

And I want to change disableConfirm state from true to first, if I change just one word in this TextInput with `useEffect`.

```
  const [disableConfirm, setDisableConfirm] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
   setDisableConfirm(false)
   }, [nameValue]);
```

The problem is when screen is first rendered, this useEffect is executed.

So disableConfirm state becomes `false` even though I don't change any word in TextInput.

How to prevent first rendering here? how to detect only change of TextInput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to achieve this would be using the `TextInput` as a controlled component.

1. First, create a state with a default value.
2. Look for changes in that state variable, if it changes from what it was originally, then enable the submit button.

Snack Implementation for the same is [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/controlled-input)

### Approach:

Declare a `state` variable with a default value

```
const [name, setName] = React.useState(SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

Now for the `TextInput`, what you can do is

```
<TextInput placeholder="Enter Name" onChangeText={setName} value={name} />
```

What this does is, it updates the field with the `name` variable every time you type something in it.

Now, to look for the changes, what you can do is,

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (name !== SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE) {
    setDisableConfirm(false);
  } else {
    /*
        You can disable the button here
        If you want user to change the textinput value 
        atleast once from what it was originally, 
        for that set disableConfirm to false here
    */
  }
}, [name]);
```